# In Critical Role Campaign 2, did Caleb keep a stock of pearls for casting Fortune's Favor?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components, critical-role-show

According to [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KXdTxewHmnBr6XTsX5pbUqZ9ObR4inZsgbaCQbMl7lc/edit#gid=311158803) compiled at Crit Role Stats, Caleb cast *fortune's favor* 36 times over the course of Campaign 2. Notably, *fortune's favor* has material component:

> a white pearl worth at least 100 gp, which the spell consumes

Now, I know Caleb had at least one pearl, often used to cast *identify* (I quote its first use in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/179582/62294)), but I do not recall Caleb ever buying more pearls or talking about the pearls being consumed for the purpose of casting *fortune's favor*. Am I remembering that correctly, or did Caleb routinely maintain a stock of pearls that were consumed by castings of *fortune's favor*, which I have just forgotten about?

The reason I ask is that I remember the spell being pretty good - a reroll on anything, attack, check, or save, at the cost of a 2nd level spell slot seems pretty decent, but having just reviewed the spell and noticed the 100 gp consumed component, it now seems like a pretty steep cost for a one-time reroll. I've been using the spell wrong, regarding my recollection of Caleb's use of it as an *in vivo* play test of the spell having no consumed costly components.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Component consumption was added in the official book.

Your memory is correct: Caleb's spell originally required a pearl as a component, but it was not consumed on casting. We can even prove this, because Liam posted a [photo of the text of the spell](https://twitter.com/VoiceOfOBrien/status/1129287168503865344) on his Twitter account.

The spell changed in the *Explorer's Guide to Wildemount* to specifically consume the pearl, and I believe they addressed that in the stream around the time that came out, though I couldn't possibly tell you which episode it was.  I do know in [episode 139](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCX70GGxpoA&t=1944s) he specifically refers to "burning" two pearls to cast the spell twice, so at least by that point he did have a supply of pearls around for the purpose.

As far as power goes, I can't really speak to that, except to say that it appears to be a conscious decision to make that change, and that suggests playtesting turned up something to justify the change.

Comment: The more I think about it the more I think you should add the second part of my answer to your own while I delete mine. Liam might have started pre-empting the book release then the book came out right into the COVID shutdown and once they were back Liam had cause to do his snorkeling expedition.

Comment: naah, leave yours on there.  Even if it's not complete, it's great information.

Comment: This matches (and explains) my recollection; I caught up on C2 from about C2E69 onwards in the past several months, so EGW was already out when I saw Caleb pick up the spell and googled to find out the details.  I initially concluded that Caleb must be using a different version of the spell that didn't consume the pearl, since he used it pretty freely for "fun" occasions and didn't initially have a lot of pearls.  But at some point he was hunting for more pearls, so by the end I'd concluded that his RP spell description included consuming them (occasionally still for fun).

Comment: I don't remember any clear statement that Fortune's Favour was now going to consume pearls being made on-stream, though.  I think I would have noticed and remembered, and I definitely remember still puzzling about whether it was consuming pearls in the final arc, concluding that it was by then.  If it had been clearly explained on-stream, I wouldn't still have been looking for clues and clear evidence (like your E139 citation) that it had changed.  (I didn't just have it on in the background, so I wouldn't have missed it.  And I watched Talks Machina so it wasn't there either.)

Answer (score 12):

### Caleb's pearlescent priorities

If you want a simple answer, yes. There's at least a half dozen mentions of Liam asking about pearls throughout Campaign 2 after gaining access to the spell. He mentions looking for pearls more than once in the two/three episode span of Nicodranas adventures before the end of the Dwendalian/Xorhas war. But, for special note, there's one time where Caleb gains a lot of pearls all at once.

#### The treasures of Vokodo's island

In the arc involving the Markoth Vokodo, the group find themselves in a place with a water plane fueled geyser that creates effectively an upside down waterfall. In this place, Caleb casts Waterbreathing on himself and spends a good long while (while the rest of the group debates how to deal with the geyser) gathering pearls. From this point on, I can't remember a time where he asks for pearls again. But then again, once this arc ends they lead swiftly on into the final arc.

Comment: Ahhh I had forgotten about him gathering pearls on Rumblecusp.

Comment: RUMBLECUSP, man I remembered to forget that name.